# Get details of all tcp listening processes

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting, grep

```
#! /bin/bash

a=`netstat -plant | grep -i listen`

#to get ip and port
b=`echo $a | awk {'print $4}'`

#to get the process id
c=`echo $a | awk {'print $7}' | awk -F '/' {'print $1'}`
set -- $c

#to get the details of process
g=`ps aux | grep $1`

m=`echo $g | awk {'print $2}'`
n=`echo $g | awk {'print $9}'`
o=`echo $g | awk {'print $11}'`


echo The process with PID $m invoked by command "$o", is listening at IP and Port : $b . The process has been running since $n
```

I was trying to make a script to display the details like PID, IP, port, running since, and the command of all tcp listening processes in a simple language. The script I made gives the details of only 1 process

Comment: Its better to use parentheses than old back-tics, example: `m=$(echo $g | awk {'print $2}'`. Also good to double quote variable, so: `m=$(echo "$g" | awk {'print $2}'` or like this: `m=$(awk {'print $2}' <<< "$g"`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change the assignment to `a` with a `while read` construct:

```
netstat -plant | grep -i listen | while read a; do

    #to get ip and port
    b=`echo $a | awk {'print $4}'`

    #to get the process id
    c=`echo $a | awk {'print $7}' | awk -F '/' {'print $1'}`
    set -- $c

    #to get the details of process
    g=`ps aux | grep $1`

    m=`echo $g | awk {'print $2}'`
    n=`echo $g | awk {'print $9}'`
    o=`echo $g | awk {'print $11}'`

    echo The process with PID $m invoked by command "$o", is listening at IP and Port : $b . The process has been running since $n

done
```

This construct will read output from the grep into `a` variable one line at a time.

Comment: Its better to use parentheses than old back-tics, example: `m=$(echo "$g" | awk {'print $2}'`.

Comment: @Jotne True. many things need to be 'fixed': why using `set --`, the strange quote position for awk, too many repeated use of awk.

Comment: is there an easier way to do this? i am new to scripting and made this script with the limited resources.

Comment: Rather than using grep, you can specify the PID directly to `ps` command with `-p` option. And fields also can be specified with `-o` option. For example: `ps -h -p $c -o pid,start_time,cmd` will show the 3 fields only for pid=$c .